# PR Ignore failed step Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, pull-request

i have a problem with pull request policies, in CI pull request i have opcional stage. i can aprove or reject opcional stage but when reject the build pipeline is failed.

is there a way is build PR is sucessed if one step is rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as a stage is rejected or fails, even if you can continue to run later stages by adding [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages),

> condition: always()

the final status of the build pipeline is still failed. This is an expected action.

And if you set [Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) as a required branch policy, the validated build must succeed in order to complete the pull request.